# Cannnot change img in material drawer

Tags: android

This is my login code via Google login.
I have already defined the drawer with account header and draweritems in onCreate method.
I'm trying to change the acccount header details in my Google log in.
I'm trying to get user details and make changes into the material drawer header.
As you see I cleared the header first when successfully logs in. Then I tried to change the name and email... I tried same with img
.withIcon (acct.getPhotoUrl()

But this didn't work. I tested this and found this in my log when LOGIN FAILED 2 is called.

> E/Drawer Login Err: java.lang.RuntimeException: please pass an activity

These are the two problems I'm facing no idea why this is happening...

```
public  void signIn()
{
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try {
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), acct.getDisplayName() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            headerResult.clear();
            headerResult.addProfiles(new ProfileDrawerItem()
                    .withEmail(acct.getEmail())
                    .withName(acct.getGivenName()));

            new DrawerBuilder()
                    .withAccountHeader(headerResult)

            //additional Drawer setup as shown above
            .build();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGIN FAILED 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGIN FAILED 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Drawer Login Err",e.toString()+"");
    }
}
```

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p67SF.png)

Comment: What does the `Drawer Login Err` say in the LogCat? "Pass an Activity"... So, where does that come from?

Comment: @cricket_007 its just the exxception that is caught

Comment: i have no idea why it says pass an activity...

Comment: logcat result i have mentioned above

Comment: Is there not more to the error message? Like a stacktrace?

Comment: the error is most likely to come in headerresult object .. ie mike penz material drawer

Comment: Probably, but I do not know that library...

Comment: @cricket_007 stacktrace in the question

Comment: i solved it .. i forgot to add activity to the drawer .. thank a lot

Comment: Cool. Feel free to answer and accept your own solution below